# Persisting objects with Realm (error: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction)

Tags: java, android, database, transactions, realm

I am having difficulties getting Realm to work.

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

MyObjectExtendingRealmObject myObject = new MyObjectExtendingRealmObject("John");
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(myObject);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction

Call me crazy but aren't I doing the data persistence inside the transaction, which is exactly how it's done in the docs? See the example using `copyToRealm` here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#creating-objects

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: What, Realm doesn't support autoincrementing primary key ids? Dealbreaker for me. I'll leave this question up in case it helps others though.

Edit: My class

```
public class MyObjectExtendingRealmObject extends RealmObject {
    private String name;

    public MyObjectExtendingRealmObject() {

    }

    public MyObjectExtendingRealmObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Autoincrementing id isn't something that Realm does out of the box, but [it's not something you cannot implement by hand in 5 minutes](https://reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/53z2kk/which_orm_solution_should_i_choose_in_2016/d7yjy6x) either

Comment: By the way, my wild guess is that your MyObjectExtendingRealmObject doesn't have a default empty constructor even though it should

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It does have a default empty constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible reasons I can see for this:

1.) you're actually calling `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` in multiple places and thus tinkering with a Realm instance that wasn't actually set to be in a transaction

2.) you don't have a default empty constructor on your realm object

---

Here is some canonical usage example:

- UI thread:

.

```
Realm realm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            MyObjectExtendingRealmObject myObject = new MyObjectExtendingRealmObject("John");
            realm.insertOrUpdate(myObject); // could be copyToRealmOrUpdate
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(realm != null) { // don't trust old devices
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

- background thread:

.

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
   realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
   realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
       @Override
       public void execute(Realm realm) {
            MyObjectExtendingRealmObject myObject = new MyObjectExtendingRealmObject("John");
            realm.insertOrUpdate(myObject); // could be copyToRealmOrUpdate
       }
   });
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

---

Realm model:

```
public class MyObjectExtendingRealmObject extends RealmObject {
   public MyObjectExtendingRealmObject() { // needed
   }

   public MyObjectExtendingRealmObject(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   @PrimaryKey
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. I only call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` once in the entire app (right now it is just MainActivity where I create an object and try to persist it). 2. My class does have a default/empty constructor. I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: In that case, I'd be curious about your exact stack trace, and which line throws the exception. Realm version 1.2.0, right?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. It's working now and I have no idea why. I don't think I changed anything, either. Answer is good anyway so I'll accept.

Comment: In that case, disable Instant Run. It tinkers with things in weird ways.

Comment: That may have been why. Disabled it now. Would it be a terrible idea to call Realm.getDefaultInstance() in the Application's onCreate() method after the RealmConfiguration initialization, set it as a global to the Application, and never call realm.close() afterward, to avoid issue #1 as you have stated it? So now if we want the default instance we call MyApp.getRealm() or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have a helper class named RealmHelper and above is one of its methods.

```
 public static void saveObject(RealmObject objectToSave) {

    Realm realm = getRealm();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(objectToSave);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Bacause of this, my code structure is this, no realm methods or object shouldn't be in activity or fragment.

For overcoming this error, everytime i create new object with same id, and realm can overwrite old object.