# Realm transaction state exception

Tags: android, database, realm

Trying to understand hot to fix quite common exception:

`Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.`

with next code:

```
realm.isInTransaction();//returns true
realmList.add(object);//IllegalStateException is thrown
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651764/persisting-objects-with-realm-error-changing-realm-data-can-only-be-done-from), most probably `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` is used in several places. But this is not the case, I just removed all `realm` instances usages. Is there way to understand why it happens? Because exception message is totally senseless: it says that transaction should be done from inside a transaction, and the same time `realm.isInTransaction` returns true. `executeTransaction` doesn't help.

Comment: Please show all code related to that place. Or publish project where problem reproduces.

Comment: @Divers it's hard to publish the whole project. I just want to understand why exception message is senseless or I would even say misleading, in other words understand what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Most probably `realmList` associated with another instance of `realm`, but without code I can only guess.

Comment: Is there way to check this association?  Like something `realm.isItAssociatedWith()`?

Comment: Well did you obtain this realm list from a RealmObject that you've obtained inside the transaction?

Comment: is the `realmList` shown in your code is `obtain` from the same `realm` instance in your code?

Comment: Thanks guys. Found the problem, it was my fault. It turned out that there was another database instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the exception message is misleading in most cases the problem is in different `Realm` instances. Check the whole code and find all calls: `Realm.getInstance` and `Realm.getDefaultInstance`. If realm object is created by `Realm.getInstance(x)` then it could not be used with `Realm.getInstance(y)` or with `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`.